# Linux - resultado incorreto com o comando find e xargs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Estou tentando listar os arquivos do último dia, porém atráves do comando abaixo ele lista os arquivos do último dia e logo em seguida começa a listar todos os arquivos:

```
[oracle@orcl11 adump]$ find . -ctime -1 | xargs ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   530 Jun  5 20:12 ./adx_orcl.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   743 Jun  5 18:24 ./orcl_ora_1987_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   750 Jun  5 18:25 ./orcl_ora_1987_2.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  1451 Jun  5 18:25 ./orcl_ora_2081_2.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  1957 Jun  5 18:41 ./orcl_ora_2096_2.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  3586 Jun  5 19:41 ./orcl_ora_2255_2.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  1442 Jun  5 18:59 ./orcl_ora_2311_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   758 Jun  5 19:01 ./orcl_ora_2361_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 21739 Jun  5 19:36 ./orcl_ora_2369_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  1403 Jun  5 19:08 ./orcl_ora_2388_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall  1172 Jun  5 19:08 ./orcl_ora_2391_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   743 Jun  5 19:41 ./orcl_ora_2513_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   750 Jun  5 19:41 ./orcl_ora_2513_2.aud
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  2024 Jun  5 19:41 ./orcl_ora_2606_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  2055 Jun  5 19:43 ./orcl_ora_2622_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  1259 Jun  5 19:52 ./orcl_ora_2729_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  4688 Jun  5 19:46 ./orcl_ora_2757_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  1689 Jun  5 19:52 ./orcl_ora_3222_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  1259 Jun  5 19:54 ./orcl_ora_3237_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   752 Jun  5 19:53 ./orcl_ora_3244_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall 38643 Jun  5 20:48 ./orcl_ora_3246_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  2160 Jun  5 20:21 ./orcl_ora_3334_1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  4368 Jun  5 20:20 ./orcl_ora_3407_1.xml

.:
total 11268
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    530 Jun  5 20:12 adx_orcl.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 28 08:49 orcl_dm00_2169_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 27 19:02 orcl_dm00_2206_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 27 19:03 orcl_dm00_2280_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 27 19:04 orcl_dm00_2286_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 27 19:05 orcl_dm00_2307_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 28 08:55 orcl_dm00_2343_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 28 08:56 orcl_dm00_2350_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 28 08:58 orcl_dm00_2402_1.aud
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   3597 May 27 19:27 orcl_dm00_2419_1.aud
...
```

Por que isso acontece? Repare que se eu utilizar apenas o comando `find` ele retorna corretamente:

```
[oracle@orcl11 adump]$ find . -ctime -1
.
./orcl_ora_2513_2.aud
./orcl_ora_1987_2.aud
./orcl_ora_2361_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2096_2.aud
./orcl_ora_2757_1.xml
./orcl_ora_3222_1.xml
./orcl_ora_2388_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2513_1.aud
./orcl_ora_3246_1.xml
./orcl_ora_2622_1.xml
./orcl_ora_3407_1.xml
./orcl_ora_2369_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2391_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2311_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2606_1.xml
./orcl_ora_3334_1.xml
./orcl_ora_1987_1.aud
./orcl_ora_2081_2.aud
./orcl_ora_2255_2.aud
./orcl_ora_3237_1.xml
./adx_orcl.txt
./orcl_ora_2729_1.xml
./orcl_ora_3244_1.xml
```

Comment: Utilize `find . -ctime -1 -print | less`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repare que o primeiro resultado do `find` é um ponto:

```
[oracle@orcl11 adump]$ find . -ctime -1
.  <--- aqui
./orcl_ora_2513_2.aud
...
```

O ponto [corresponde ao diretório atual](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html). E o `xargs` irá repassar o ponto para o `ls` (juntamente com os nomes dos arquivos encontrados).

E quando o `ls` recebe uma lista de arquivos e um diretório como parâmetros, ele lista os arquivos e em seguida lista também o conteúdo do diretório.

É isso que está acontecendo: primeiro são listados os arquivos que o `find` encontrou, e depois a listagem com todos os arquivos é o resultado de passar o `.` (o diretório atual) para o `ls`.

Para que isso não aconteça, você pode usar a opção `-type` e fazer com que o `find` só encontre os arquivos (ignorando diretórios):

```
find . -ctime -1 -type f | xargs ls -l
```

No caso, `-type f` faz com que só sejam listados arquivos, assim o `.` não é listado. Veja todas as opções na [documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: Muito bem observado, muito obrigado!

Comment: cool; ou `find . -ctime -1 | xargs ls -ld`